# Core Plot CPTGraphHostingView corner radius

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, core-plot

is it possible to set corner radius for CPTGraphHostingView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but why would you need to? All Core Plot drawing is done by Core Animation layers (CPTGraph and all of it's various pieces). You can set the corner radius on the graph and on many other layers. Any graph part that is a subclass of CPTBorderedLayer can take a corner radius.

Comment: Thanks got what I wanted by setting the cornerradius on CPTXYGraph

Answer (score 0):

Make the **HostView** background clear color and set the background property and corner radius of the graph. This worked for me:

```
hostView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
graph.backgroundColor=[UIColor brownColor];
graph.cornerRadius=10.0f;
```